# On Calculating Expectation Values in Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Expectation value $\langle A\rangle=\langle \alpha|A|\alpha\rangle$. Which can be written as $\langle A\rangle = \sum_{a}\sum_{b} \langle\alpha|b\rangle \langle b|A|a\rangle\langle a|\alpha\rangle$.

How is $\langle A\rangle = \sum_{a}\sum_{b} \langle\alpha|b\rangle \langle b|A|a\rangle\langle a|\alpha\rangle=\sum_{a} a|\langle a|\alpha\rangle|^2$?,

where $A = \sum_{a} a\Lambda_{a}$

and $\sum_{a}\Lambda_{a} = \sum_{a} |a\rangle\langle a|=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the definitions imply $A |a\rangle = a |a\rangle$, $|\langle a | \alpha \rangle|^2 = \langle a | \alpha \rangle\langle \alpha | a \rangle$ and $\sum_b |b\rangle\langle b | = 1$. Substituting these expressions on the expression you provided for $\langle A \rangle$ leads to the desired conclusion.